# Check if strings are the same

Tags: c, recursion

I need to build a **recursive function** named `one` that gets two pointers, `char *S1` and `char *s2` which are pointers to 2 strings

The function returns `1` and `printf` if there is a difference in only 1 character.

***for example:***

```
s1=abcde
s2=abcdf

\\return 1

s1=abc
s2=abc

\\return 0
```

I code it and it's almost working, when `s1="dor"` and `s2="dors"` the function doesn't work.

But when `s2="dors"` and `s1="dor"` it's working. I cannot use static so I tried to save the difference counter in the end of the string (told string length < 50 so I allocated `s1[52]` and `s2[52]`)

```
int one(char* s1, char* s2){
    int Length1,Length2;
    Length2=(int)(strlen(s2));
    Length1=(int)(strlen(s1));
    if(Length1<Length2){
        if((*s1=='\0')&&(*s2=='\0')&& *(s2+Length2)=='1'){
            printf("1\n");
            return 1;
        }

            return one(s1+1,s2+1);
        }
        else{
            if(*(s2+Length2)=='1')
            {printf("0\n");
                return 0;
            }

            *(s2+Length2)='1';
            return one(s1+1, s2+1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If `*s1 == '\0'` and `$s2 == '\0'` then both `Length1` and `Length2` will be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to get the length of the strings. There are just three cases you need to concern yourself with:

1. Both strings are empty, then they're equal, so you return 0.
2. The first character of each string is different, so you return 1.
3. The first character is the same, you need to recurse starting with the 2nd character of each string.

Case #2 will handle the case where the strings are different lengths, because when you reach the end of the shorter string during the recursion, its first character will be '\0' while the first character of the other string will be something else.

```
int one(char *s1, char *s2) {
    if (*s1 == '\0' && *s2 == '\0') {
        return 0;
    } else if (*s1 != *s2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return one(s1+1, s2+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all thank you!
But i think your code will not work in case of
s1=abbb
s2=bccc
because, accordintg to your pseudo code it will return 1 as you check s1[0] and s2[0]. also the function one does not print "1" or "0" as it should be

Comment: @d.s: that's a more complex algorithm, then. Please edit your question to show the extra examples and the required output (presumably 0).  If the strings are "Xabcdefg" and "abcdefg", do those count as differing in one place?  What about "abcdXefg" and "abcdefg"?  Your "dor" and "dors" example indicates that my "abcdefgX" and "abcdefg" equivalent should produce 1.  Are there other examples?  "abcdXefg" and "abcdYefg" differ in one place, too.

Answer (score 1):

This should print `1` if there is only one character that is different or one additional character in otherwise identical strings. If the strings are the same or the differences are two or more, then `0` will be printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 100

int one ( char *a, char *b, int diff) {

    int alen = strlen ( a);
    int blen = strlen ( b);

    if ( abs ( alen - blen) > 1 || diff > 1) {//more than one difference
        printf ( "0\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if ( !*a && !*b) {//end of the two strings
        printf ( "%d\n", diff);
        return diff;
    }
    if ( *b != *a) {//a difference
        diff++;
        //increment the longer string
        if ( strlen ( a) < strlen ( b)) {
            return one ( a, ++b, diff);
        }
        if ( strlen ( b) < strlen ( a)) {
            return one ( ++a, b, diff);
        }
    }
    return one ( ++a, ++b, diff);
}

int main()
{
    char first[SIZE] = { '\0'};
    char second[SIZE] = { '\0'};
    while ( 1) {
        printf ( "\nenter x to exit or\n");
        printf ( "enter first  string: ");
        fflush ( stdout);//make sure prompt is printed
        if ( !( fgets ( first, SIZE, stdin))) {
            printf ( "problem getting input\n");
            exit ( 1);
        }
        if ( strcmp ( first, "x\n") == 0) {
            break;
        }
        printf ( "enter second string: ");
        fflush ( stdout);//make sure prompt is printed
        if ( !( fgets ( second, SIZE, stdin))) {
            printf ( "problem getting input\n");
            exit ( 1);
        }
        if ( strcmp ( second, "x\n") == 0) {
            break;
        }
        printf ( "\nresult from \"one\" is %d\n", one ( first, second, 0));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `diff` argument to the externally called function is unfortunate, but close to unavoidable unless you create a wrapper function that doesn't take the `diff` argument and calls a second function that does.